# C++ remove punctuation marks and spaces from a string

Tags: c++

How can I remove punctuation marks and spaces from a string in a simple way without using any library functions?

Comment: Loop over the string, keeping track of two positions: the "write head" and the "read head". When the read head hits a punctuation mark, skip it forward without writing. Otherwise copy from the read head to the write head, and move both forward.

Comment: Is the standard library also forbidden?  And std::string? Are the punctuation marks only ".,;:?!" or is it anything that is not alphanumeric?

Comment: @stefaanv anything not alphanumeric

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    string s = "abc de.fghi..jkl,m no";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '.' || s[i] == ',')
        {
            s.erase(i, 1); // remove ith char from string
            i--; // reduce i with one so you don't miss any char
        }
    }
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Comment: `std::string::operator[]` is a library function, so this code doesn't meet the requirement to not use any library functions. <g>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use library I/O like `<iostream>` and types like `std::string` and you just don't want to use the `<cctype>` functions like `ispunct()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    const std::string myString = "This. is a string with ,.] stuff in, it.";
    const std::string puncts = " [];',./{}:\"?><`~!-_";
    std::string output;

    for (const auto& ch : myString)
    {
        bool found = false;

        for (const auto& p : puncts)
        {
            if (ch == p)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found)
            output += ch;
    }

    std::cout << output << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

No idea about the performance, I'm sure it can be done in multiple better ways.

Comment: Um, the (obviously artificial) constraint is to not use **any** library functions. The constructor for `std::string` is a library function. <g> And, behind the scenes, that for loop uses `std::string::begin()` and `std::string::end()`, which are also library functions.

Comment: Then might as well go to C style and use arrays, tho even there will have to use some functions like `strlen()`, `strcat()` or even `printf()`. I doubt his requirements are that strict, but since he didn't elaborate guess we'll never know.

Comment: I suspect that the point is to write your own equivalents of `strlen` and `strcat`; they're not that hard to do. `printf`, on the other hand,...